# Restart game after after 2 minutes of inactivity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, restart

I'm trying to figure out how to begin writing a piece of code that listens for user activity. If there is absolutely no activity after a few minutes I want the game to restart. Can someone recommend a good starting point to get something like this working?

Comment: Hi. Are you mostly struggling with the actual timer or with the problem of getting any and all user interaction to influence the timer?

Comment: I was looking for guidance on how to start implementing this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wondering how to capture all input from everywhere, take a look at

```
Input.anyKeyDown
```

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-anyKeyDown.html

In addition you can also check that the mouse position is still the same as the previous frame. Use this in combination with @Neeraj Kumar's answer i.e.

```
private Vector3 prevMousePosition = Vector3.zero;
void Update()
{
    if(Input.anyKeyDown || Input.mousePosition != prevMousePosition)
         RestartGameInvoke();

     prevMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One way is to take advantage of Invoke function.

```
    void Start()
    {
        RestartGameInvoke();
    }

    void RestartGameInvoke()
    {
        CancelInvoke ();
        Invoke ("RestartGame", 10);
    }
    void RestartGame()
    {
        //
    }
```

You can call RestartGameInvoke(); if any user activity happens. If no activity happens then game will restart in 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is in regards to the unity api, you can set up a timer via the update method. Use Time.deltaTime inside the Update method to create a timer and once the elapsed time has passed do what it is you like. The trick here is check for any input via the mouse/keyboard depending on your scenario. If keyboard or mouse input has been met, then reset the few minutes that have passed to 0 when comparing to the time has passed inside the update method.